# I/O inside thread still generates android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

Tags: android-service, ioexception

The following code generates `android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException`

What am I doing wrong?

```
Thread t = new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        Intent i = new Intent(EntryActivity.this, UpdateBizLocationService.class);
        startService(i);
    }
};
t.start();
```

[Intent](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.robolectric/android-all/5.0.0_r2-robolectric-1/android/content/Intent.java#Intent.%3Cinit%3E%28%29) class source

Comment: How do you know that's where the exception is being generated from?

Comment: @clearlight I'm using debugger. Inside the service there is an http call: HttpURLConnection conn; ... os = conn.getOutputStream(); there's where the exception occurs. Thanks for the edit, btw.

Comment: What's going on in the `Intent` class?

Comment: The service is collecting location information. When updated I'm POSTing that information to web server.

Comment: I meant specifically - e.g. *how* is it doing that. Maybe it's starting something on the main thread. Do you have the source? Is it available online, if it can't be reasonably posted in your answer? Do you have a link? What is the imported package of the Intent class?

Comment: OK, wait a second, you're simply starting a service inside the thread. That *doesn't* imply the service itself is running inside the thread. The classes `EntryActivity`, `UpdateBizLocationService` may be the culprits. Assuming those are your classes and the service is running the Intent on the main thread, if your class(es) do network I/O that could explain it. You might have to ensure the network activity done in the background there. Are those your classes and do they do I/O?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Android Services official documentation:

> Remember that if you do use a service, it still runs in your
>   application's main thread by default, so you should still create a new
>   thread within the service if it performs intensive or blocking
>   operations.

https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

So, you need to create a new thread **within** you service, not outside.

Or use **IntentService** which already uses worker thread: 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html

Comment: Yep. That did it. Thank you and thanks to clearlight for trying to help.